# Removing N rows of multiple CSV and then Merging them

Tags: csv, cmd, command-prompt

I have a folder with multiple (dozens) CSV files, and need to merge them in a bigger CSV, but removing the first n rows of each individual file, and wanted to do that in a bulk operation.

I've seen here some solutions like the "more" command, but to use it i would have to run it once for each small CSV, and that's what i want to avoid - i will have to do this process daily.

To merge all CSVs, i can use (all CSVs are in the same folder):

copy *.csv AllData.csv

Is there a similar approach, with wildcards or something like that, to remove the first n rows of the CSVs?

BTW i'm running Windows, but can install programs if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This would be super easy in [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Assuming you want to skip the first 7 rows, a script would look like this:
(untested...)

```
n = 7

Loop, *.csv
{   
    Tooltip, Reading %A_LoopFileName%
    Loop, read, %A_LoopFileName%
    {

        If (A_Index<=n)
          continue
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, AllData.csv
    }
}    
Tooltip,
msgbox, Done
```